# SpriteBatch is not applicable for the arguments JAVA libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, spritebatch

I am trying to use sprite batch to rotate a rectangle with a texture like so:

game.batch.draw(Image, (float)x, (float)y, (float)42.5, (float)33, (float)85, (float)66, (float)1, (float)1, (float)angleDegrees);

But i get the error:

```
The method draw(Texture, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float) in the type SpriteBatch is not applicable for the arguments (Texture, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float)
```

I think i have the right amount of parameters, and they are all floats, what am i missing.

Comment: I cannot find that mathod signature in the documentation: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.html please which of these methods you are trying to call.

Comment: @kajacx Draws a rectangle with the bottom left corner at x,y and stretching the region to cover the given width and height. The rectangle is offset by originX, originY relative to the origin. Scale specifies the scaling factor by which the rectangle should be scaled around originX, originY. Rotation specifies the angle of counter clockwise rotation of the rectangle around originX, originY. 
Specified by: draw(...) in Batch
Parameters:
region 
x 
y 
originX 
originY 
width 
height 
scaleX 
scaleY 
rotation

Comment: @kajacx void com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Batch.draw(TextureRegion region, float x, float y, float originX, float originY, float width, float height, float scaleX, float scaleY, float rotation)

Comment: Ah, i didn't see that one because it requires a `TextureRegion` instead of a `Texture`, but they are not in subtype releationship, thus the error. Try converting your texture to `TextureRegion` then.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have the right amount of parameters. You have one float too much.
Thats how I would put it in an editor to see whats the problem by such a bunch of parameters.

```
The method draw(
Texture, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float) 
in the type SpriteBatch is not applicable for the arguments (
Texture, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, **float**)
```

Comment: Are u sure '(region, x, y, originX, originY, width, height, scaleX, scaleY, rotation)'    any idea wich one?

Comment: From your error message: yes. Copy the error message to a editor format it that you could see the falsy parameter, thats what I did.

Comment: you can do this in every editor, its just a tool to visualize about which parameter java is complaining.

Comment: i c now but the problem is if i get rid of the rotate then how can i rotate the item?